# mvc3 - How to disable htmlencode of symbols from source

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

I need to out on my page text from database table. Table field "Text" Contains text with html formatting tags like `<p>, <br/>` etc... (in table its not encoded!)

When i'm trying to output with @Model.Text i see encoded html tags like `&lt;p&gt;`
How can i disable this html-encode. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Raw(Model.Text)` to achieve this.

Comment: I love short answers to frustrating problems.

Comment: nop not worked for me it's given <p> </p> contain? please help

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the <%: syntax in your views, it will automatically encode all output.  Using <%= does not perform the encoding.

More details can be found at http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-in-lt-variable-gt-and-lt-variable-gt-in-asp-net-mvc/